# Local Maven Repository M2 Sync with Nexus Release Deletion

Tags: maven, jenkins, repository, nexus

Coming from Maven integration with Artifactory, now I'm facing Nexus, that's a good thing!

I just want to know what could be the best way for you to perform the below action.

When i delete some releases of Nexus (eg 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3), i would link to sync the deletion with our Jenkins Maven local repository (.m2), in order to keep it clean, and without perform a manual deletion...

I know that a good answer could be just clean .m2 every week or something like this, but in this case it will spend many times to download all the artifacts needed...

So, have you an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only sync i can think of would be an external source that have access to both file system. You can clean up your nexus with the job section in nexus. As for jenkins there is plugin that clean up the .m2 repository

Comment: I think people focus too much on avoiding download dependencies. The entire point of running Nexus/Artifactory locally is to cache files from the internet. I subscribe the the KISS principle, purging the local repo is by far the simplest solution here and pays a small download penalty. Lastly deleting releases *should* be an infrequent activity (It's why snapshot releases were invented). Releases are supposed to be a permanent record or line in the sand of your development.

Comment: Deleting releases is violating one of the basic principles in Maven repositories. A release is immutable. So one thing is the repository (Nexus) and one is your local cache which as already @MarkO'Connor mentioned the simplest solution is to simply delete it...and apart from that why do you think you need to delete the local cache very week ?

Comment: First thanks for all the answers, KISS always useful, and obviously releases should not be deleted... But sometime reality is different, when you have 32 GB of old releases cached, and for some product, old releases, for company choice, should not be collected...